# Does removing a DOM element remove the associated scope?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, scopes are associated with DOM elements. If you call `$element.remove()`, does `$element.scope().$destroy()` end up getting called as well? Or is the developer responsible for cleaning up scopes himself?

This makes me think that it removing a DOM element should automatically remove the scope:

**angular.js**

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
// jQuery mutation patch
//
//  In conjunction with bindJQuery intercepts all jQuery's DOM destruction apis and fires a
// $destroy event on all DOM nodes being removed.
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////

function JQLitePatchJQueryRemove(name, dispatchThis) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT:

Angular 1.2.X now [patches JQuery to call $destroy](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/933537860247de35c21db060ae9ae1f87bb30d53/src/jqLite.js#L166)

However, I haven't tested to see if I got the same results I saw before.

(Thanks @KumarHarsh for pointing this out in the comments)

---

#### Old answer (Angular 1.0.X):

No, `$element.remove()` doesn't remove the scope, presumably because the scope is still referenced by other scopes.

As proof you can remove a scoped element from a nested controller, then load the scope from the parent controller and check `$$childHead` to see the child scope still exists.

[Here is a plunk to demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZiPJF)

Also, you can view the scopes in memory using the [Batarang plugin for Chrome](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang)

Comment: For some reason the batarang plugin works very intermittently for me.

Comment: I think their last update has some issues. You may want to pull their latest .zip from github and install that.

Comment: Looking into Angular's source, they are now **patching** each jquery function and call the `$destroy()` event.

Comment: @KumarHarsh A quick question: if someone side-loads a pristine version of jquery thusly forcing angular to use that over its own built-in jquery, will this mean that the $destroy() event will *not* be triggered upon $element.remove()? Based on my tests this appears to be the case. Just thought to drop a line or two to make sure I'm not misinterpreting anything here. Thanks in advance and thumbs up for the headsup about jquery's patching.

Comment: From what I've learnt, I think Angular requires jQuery to be preloaded to utilize jQuery's `$` instead of it's jqlite. Therefore, there could be issues with sideloading.

Comment: The Angular patch only triggers element.on("$destroy", ... ), which is not the same thing as $scope.$on("$destroy", ... )

Comment: AFAICT angular.js no longer patches remove as of commit d71dbb1.  It's not clear to me whether my code needs to change as a result.